# Problem Upgrading to ubuntu 15, cant access files

Tags: upgrade

So I had Ubuntu v14 installed (not sure of the exact) . A message popped up asking if I wanted to upgrade to v15. I agreed and the installation began. I checked on my computer a while later and the installation had froze. I left it for an hour and still no progress and the window was unresponsive. This is where I made the mistake of shutting down my computer, In fact I had to do a hard shutdown.

I should not of done that. When I next came to use my computer it started fine but then i was presented with the log on screen. I typed my password in but the terminal came up for a split second and then returned to the log in screen.

I've tried recovery mode, the same problem. I then created a new install disk. I could then get access to my files but when I've tried to back them up it says I'm not the owner so I cant copy them.

I have the option of deleting everything and reinstalling but I really don't want to delete all my files....But unless I log on as my user it wont recognize me as the owner.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Put the Ubuntu DVD into the DVD-drive and restart the computer.

You should see a welcome screen prompting you to choose your language.

Choose your preferred language and click on ‘Try Ubuntu’.

Your live desktop should appear.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

Suppose the fdisk reports / (root) is /dev/sda1, continue running:

```
umount /dev/sda1
fsck -a /dev/sda1
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

**Replace /dev/sda1 with his /.**